# Why is Yoruichi able to transform?

Tags: bleach

Why/how is Yoruichi Shihōin able to transform into a cat? Was she always able to or did she learn it somehow? Does she have some object that allows here to?

As far as I can remember she seems the only one to be able to transform (into an animal).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Bleach Wiki's page on the character](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Yoruichi_Shih%C5%8Din#Powers_.26_Abilities):

> Yoruichi possess the unique ability to shape-shift into a black cat at will. How she alone, out of all Shinigami, is capable of this is currently unknown. She has possessed the ability for well over 100 years, and it's known to others she knew from that time. She apparently has no set time limit on the transformation, as she had been in this form for over 100 years.

Basically, it is unknown.

Comment: So she basically is just a strange case? Disappointing... ;)

Comment: @Veger We can only hope she's not the only one...

Comment: Sir Mittens was in his form for a long time too.